# How reliable is the multipass cli on macOS for pentesting?

Tags: macos

I've been using `multipass` to quicly spin up vm's on my mac for my some CS courses which required a linux distro, but I'm getting into pentesting and will need a solution. Any advice or opinions on the tool welcome. I wouldn't want to start using it and then 3 months into it realising I need to rethink my setup.

Cheers

Comment: "Reliable" in what way? I'm not sure what you are asking or what requirements pentesting might have that you are expecting.

Comment: Well... for example, is it a good virtualisation software, does it have any limitations which would render its use unpractical ? Maybe some networking requirements that may not be met, or you may also just share your experience with it. Not sure why they've closed the question.

Comment: It's closed because it is unclear how this is a security question. "Is it good" -- for what exactly? "Does it have limitations?" -- yes, all virtualisation have CPU, RAM, and networking limitations. If it has the tools you need, then it works for you.